# HTTP 1.1 400 Unknown version Rest API create defect HPALM

Tags: json, rest, curl, hp-alm

Hi I am trying to create defect from Rest API into HPALM.

I am using following command. I am getting an error:

```
 HTTP/1.1 400 Unknown Version

 C:\Adwait>curl -D- -X POST --data-binary @C:\Adwait\HPCreateDefect.json -H "Authorization: Basic RGVtb" -H "Content-Type:application/json" "http://ServerURL:8080/qcbin/rest/domains/DEMO_PURPOSE\/projects/DEMO_01/defects HTTP/1.1" -k

HTTP/1.1 400 Unknown Version

Content-Length: 0

Connection: close

Server: Jetty(9.1.4.v20140401)
```

Comment: `HTTP/1.1` doesn't belong in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

@Adwait please check how you write the link above.

Even if suggested in some libraries from HP, you do not have to add the HTTP/1.1 at the end of the link used.

Please check and close the query itself. I had in the beginning same problem creating a python interface for the QC REST API.
Have a nice day!